# The change from "activity" to "activities" for the tab on the user profile page is kind of weird

Tags: discussion, status-completed, profile-page, recent-activity

I notice that the tab on the user profile page formerly known as "activity" is now called "activities".

[image: so much space for "activities"]

This is kind of weird wording. It suggests that each entry visible when you're on that tab is "an activity". Posting a comment or accepting an answer is not really something that I conceptualize as "an activity", though those things are certainly part of "my activity on the site".

Perhaps we should call this tab "actions" instead, like the header says when you're on the "all" view of the tab:

[image: 430 actions]

(Yeah, this *really* isn't important at all, but I haven't gotten any good bikeshedding done lately, so...)

Comment: Yeah that's weird.  We'll adjust.

Answer (score 3):

"Activity" (in its uncountable sense) was absolutely fine.

No idea why it was changed. I'd like to see it changed back.

Comment: I think something broke when a tab was nested in another tab with the same name (Activity/Activity).  But you're right - "Activities" sounds like a typo to me. We'll adjust it.

Comment: @Jaydles: Ta :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that this was changed to disambiguate with the new "Activity" (as opposed to "Profile") top-level view.  (In particular, I suspect this helps with named classes in the CSS.)

[image: new top-level tabs]

But "activities" seems weird to me too; that tab represents the *collected activit**y*** on my account, including "activities" that didn't involve my direct participation (like earning badges).

I seem to recall that the suggestion was already made, and rejected, to rename the new "Activity" tab to something else.  If we can't have little-A "activity" any more, how about "events"?  This tab shows comments, posts, revisions, badges, suggested edits -- all things that could be considered events.

If "events" isn't acceptable, then even "actions" would be better than "activities", though it has the same "you didn't necessarily *do* everything here" problem that "activities" does.  "Actions" is better than "activities"; "events" would be better; "activity" would be even better but might no longer be available to us.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this as well. It reminds me of the scene from the movie "Step Brothers" when they talk about all the room/time they will have to get "activities" done now.

[image]

I definitely agree that changing it to Actions would be more suitable. Also, it still says "Activity" on the main SE. https://stackexchange.com/users/3648514/bluet?tab=activity